# JavaScript global functions and eval use for YouTube API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube API to control several you-tube videos.  And I'm following the [google code example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#working_with_multiple_players).  But the problem is that they require a global string for their listener callback.

```
ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onPlayerStateChange");
```

where `ytplayer` is the "object" element that contains the flash video player.  Following their example it seems I need to create a new global function for each player -- `onPlayerStateChange2`, etc.  They don't allow function references (anonymous or otherwise) in place of the string, and locally defined strings don't work either.  How can I avoid explicitly named global functions?  The following works

```
var localStateChangeHandler = function (newState) {
  updateHTML("playerState", newState);
}
var globalStateChangeString = 'onPlayerStateChange'+ytplayer.id;
eval(globalStateChangeString + ' = localStateChangeHandler');
ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", globalStateChangeString);
```

but it's not very pretty, it's still creating global functions, and is using an "eval".  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could encapsulate it inside a single object and use currying to hide multiple global functions. Let's say you have a global object and with a dispatchEvent method on it.

```
Player = {};

Player.dispatchEvent = function(id) {
    var player = document.getElementById(id);
    return function(newState) {
        console.log("player id %s changed state to %s", id, newState);
    };
};
```

Then add a call to dispatchEvent as a string with the correct id, when adding the state change event listener.

```
var call = 'Player.dispatchEvent("{id}")'.replace("{id}", somePlayerId);
ytplayer.addEventListener('onStateChange', call);
```

When the string is eval'd by Youtube, it would return a reference to an anonymous function that holds the player id through a closure, and receives the state change parameter in the next invocation.

I have written a small class [YoutubePlayer](https://github.com/AnuragMishra/YoutubePlayer), inspired by this [blog](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2008/05/22/dispatching-youtube-api-events-to-individual-javascript-objects/) article, to play multiple videos and handle events from each one of them separately while keeping the global state minimal, which you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks, you even answered my unwritten bonus question of how to get the callback function to execute in the context of the player.

Comment: The YoutubePlayer object does not work. It does not capture the events.

Comment: This is a big help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718404/retrieve-player-state-with-multiple-youtube-players-on-a-page